# LINQ text box matches database

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am trying to run the following in a LINQ update statement.

```
if (updateProfile.website == txtSite.Text) { }
else { updateProfile.website = txtSite.Text; }
```

This simply checkes to see if the textbox value matches the one in the DB, if it does then it moves on, if not it updates it.

The problem i have is that if the textbox is empty its passing in "" so a blank value. I would like it to move on if the textbox is "", this way it leaves the null value in the DB.

All help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use want `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`, which pretty much does what it says:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSite.Text) || updateProfile.website == txtSite.Text) { }
else { updateProfile.website = txtSite.Text; }
```

Alternatively, if you *only* care about the value `""` and want to treat it distinctly from `null`, you can just check for that explicitly:

```
if (txtSite.Txt == "" || updateProfile.website == txtSite.Text) { }
else { updateProfile.website = txtSite.Text; }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, worked a treat! - I just used the 1st suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

or you can check your textbox like this and then add your conditions

```
if (txtSite.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
{
    if (updateProfile.website == txtSite.Text) { }
    else { updateProfile.website = txtSite.Text; }
}
```